# Why does toString fail to produce the correct value on an immutable BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class BigDecimalTest {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    // 4.88...e+888 (1817 digits)
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("4.8832420563130171734733855852454330503023811919919497272520875234748556667894678622576481754268427107559208829679871295885797242917923401597269406065677191699322289667695163278484184288979073748578074654323955355081326227413484377691676742424283166095829482224974429868654315166151274143385980609237680132582337344627820946638217515894542788180511625488217105374918015830882194114839900966043221545533114607439892553114356192220778082796185122942407317178325055570254731781136589172583464356709469398354084238614163644229733602505332671951571644165960364672255033809137641462904872690406789293887232669588297154237004709334039097468524122773548736567569610163195984254280720739773383424940292419418795538600322135358425131164741597944425501875163782825762694824406500718290697914964822219714335320528259344719705157913218736206355811213275685167080292570345461898557739737178480700932922510537942188898832900701474604169230215866582286672118698263686941093382945779882215421032414999405126831495224267159359035083987132591639397950272617333366716471522059176764287433877865132652162238979110053714139119937420203828830308427979430335027147927304099711225033972679405835031675622271744826476172494554124259735452592820489036311645033355738586053207859638698142614469753279404304130088308403735928520706825401977138623732336487326694527108332032932321484204820451539099031068139840323111890984119271864483907126875945501867099986131423579718697889448836497435592993168391953327829695391643033262276364164246663414855044991442223872210174626308430613254236633497864858897399515832571171741522071020097519091890029843359547212185712419638040776450730043492270253991396124987467648536016180816769990203447616590740625203442076233929983869509074724986395815800482885710533831896927860285993286232937744729344906236207008084e+888");
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("7.11510949782866099699296193137700951609335763543887012748548458182417747578081585833524887774072570691956766860384875364912060891737185872746005419263400444156198098581226885923291670353816772414798224148927688218647602446762953730527741703572368727049379249227044080281137229152770971832240631944592537904743732558993126e+302");
    BigDecimal z = x.divide(y, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    System.out.println("x: " + x.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("y: " + y.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("z: " + z.toString());
  }
}
```

Compile

```
>javac BigDecimalTest.java
```

Execute

```
 >java BigDecimalTest
```

Output

```
x: 625054983208066198204593354911415430438704792574969565088267203004781525349051886368978966454635866976757873019902352587338204709349419540445048397640668053751325307746498089964597558898932143981799355575346628545040975710892600034453462303030824526026617372479672702318775234126736309035340551798242305697053918011236108116969184203450147688710548806249178948798950602635292084669950732365353235782823866975230624679863759260425959459791169573662813659882560711299260566798548341409068343765881208298932278254261294646140590112068258200980117045324292667804864432756961810725182370437206902961756578170730203574233660279475700447597108771501423828064891010088908598454793225469099307839235742968560582894084123332587841678908692453688646424002096420169762493752403209194120933311549724412343492102761719612412226021289199823441354383529928770138627744900421912301539068635884552971941408134.8856600179050611289788749333661467630922532694031193377751928459953017059824923573892149119923856234431388706196397956490750352971729842937634895018670939708354823574625828791536366736979476766589326086875409807351989786090090279478781367082883474934694924763036804348502963946884054479650783337788950079302927905246137931881022596647890564269534539014810606033753362254652128419763750928651303475678198850650473651453073743837739070377816899469866500215337149978217017797004675976721899561358322045967266798653940112240121024238988798224822218203993329849451071671755903125554170025962201010130308257571374613023572917101445758904604655642902352167479118496542289087726701938867138026569109982914825090572482443761923819950022043159771189713669219385693445567010592510898703998395859012610071144546558746041294923614800026040585757943037935297161564798258664422461809370948330482806766116607140637816031325356147998234497034752

y: 711510949782866099699296193137700951609335763543887012748548458182417747578081585833524887774072570691956766860384875364912060891737185872746005419263400444156198098581226885923291670353816772414798224148927688218647602446762953730527741703572368727049379249227044080281137229152770971832240631944592537.904743732558993126

z: 6863200148645991450016700150728475158275817266239021182863526677885700921863906334312309256001619020949572592642200844420107346867400206096485382274175041601107978676753014927820457112641389679172479926134263590581506384223135957016211147412682886175625161361918270282067511320630977561140325469899962049739132122854543111824994613211802165652292305592183629295330885779837415870933600699791946039851356918600890315497940083093271504897016557099915008808164166772999720870505507779642391694002178573568389923682384862328430119487673749084566046514914589822168578412569408216619911686172
```

The value of `z.toString()` in the output is correct

```
4.883242e+888 / 7.115109e+302 = 6.863200e+585
```

as is the value of `y.toString()`, but notice that the value given for `x.toString()` is completely wrong.

Why is this?

Strangely, if the scale (i.e. desired decimal places) of the result of the division is changed

```
BigDecimal z = x.divide(y, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

then `x.toString()` will produce the correct value for `x`.

Or, if the operands are swapped

```
BigDecimal z = y.divide(x, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

then `x.toString()` will also then produce the correct value.

Or, if the exponent of `x` is changed from `e+888` to e.g. `e+878` then  `x.toString()` will be correct.

Or, if another `x.toString()` call is added above the `divide` operation, then *both* `x.toString()` calls will produce the correct value!

On the machine I'm testing this, Windows 7 64 bit, the behaviour is the same using java 7 and 8, both 32bit and 64 bit versions, but testing online at https://ideone.com/ produces different results for java 7 and java 8.

Using java 7, the value of `x` is given correctly: http://ideone.com/P1sXQQ, but using java 8 its value is incorrect: http://ideone.com/OMAq7a.

Also, this behaviour is not unique to this particular value of `x`, as calling `toString` on other BigDecimals with more than about 1500 digits after passing them as the first operand to a `divide` operation will also produce incorrect values.

What is the explanation for this?

The `divide` operation seems to be mutating the value produced by subsequent `toString` calls on its operands.

Does this happen on your platform?

*Edit:*

The issue seems to be with the java 8 runtime only, as the above program compiled with java 7 produces correct output when executed with the java 7 runtime, but incorrect output when executed with the java 8 runtime.

*Edit:*

I've tested with the early access [jre1.8.0_60](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and the bug does not appear, and according to Marco13's answer it was fixed in build 51. The Oracle JDK 8 product binaries are only at update 40 though so it may be some time before the fixed versions are widely used.

Comment: *"Or, if another x.toString() call is added above the divide operation, then both x.toString() calls will produce the correct value!"* That's the bit that I find really scary. And it happens for me (64-bit Java 1.8.0_20 on Linux).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try with apfloat?

Comment: I believe this is a bug that should be submitted to the java bug tracker.

Comment: your code shows the valid output on my pc (I'm using java version "1.8.0_31"). I'm curious, what is your java version and update number?

Comment: @kucing_terbang jdk1.8.0_31. And the Ideone link above appears to use sun-jdk-8u25. Also incorrect on 64 bit jdk1.8.0_05. It may be a 64 bit jdk problem only.

Comment: No, it is incorrect using 32 bit jre-1.8.0_31 also.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not so hard to track down the *reason* for the odd behavior.

The `divide` call goes to

```
public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    return divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode.oldMode);
}
```

This, internally, delegates to another `divide` method, based on the rounding mode:

```
public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode) {
    if (roundingMode < ROUND_UP || roundingMode > ROUND_UNNECESSARY)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid rounding mode");
    if (this.intCompact != INFLATED) {
        if ((divisor.intCompact != INFLATED)) {
            return divide(this.intCompact, this.scale, divisor.intCompact, divisor.scale, scale, roundingMode);
        } else {
            return divide(this.intCompact, this.scale, divisor.intVal, divisor.scale, scale, roundingMode);
        }
    } else {
        if ((divisor.intCompact != INFLATED)) {
            return divide(this.intVal, this.scale, divisor.intCompact, divisor.scale, scale, roundingMode);
        } else {
            return divide(this.intVal, this.scale, divisor.intVal, divisor.scale, scale, roundingMode);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the last call applies. Note that the `intVal` (which is a `BigInteger` that is stored in the `BigDecimal`) is passed directly to this method as the first argument:

```
private static BigDecimal divide(BigInteger dividend, int dividendScale, BigInteger divisor, int divisorScale, int scale, int roundingMode) {
    if (checkScale(dividend,(long)scale + divisorScale) > dividendScale) {
        int newScale = scale + divisorScale;
        int raise = newScale - dividendScale;
        BigInteger scaledDividend = bigMultiplyPowerTen(dividend, raise);
        return divideAndRound(scaledDividend, divisor, scale, roundingMode, scale);
    } else {
        int newScale = checkScale(divisor,(long)dividendScale - scale);
        int raise = newScale - divisorScale;
        BigInteger scaledDivisor = bigMultiplyPowerTen(divisor, raise);
        return divideAndRound(dividend, scaledDivisor, scale, roundingMode, scale);
    }
}
```

Finally, the path to the **second** `divideAndRound` is taken here, again passing the `dividend` on (which was the `intVal` of the original `BigDecimal`), ending up with this code:

```
private static BigDecimal divideAndRound(BigInteger bdividend, BigInteger bdivisor, int scale, int roundingMode,
                                         int preferredScale) {
    boolean isRemainderZero; // record remainder is zero or not
    int qsign; // quotient sign
    // Descend into mutables for faster remainder checks
    MutableBigInteger mdividend = new MutableBigInteger(bdividend.mag);
    MutableBigInteger mq = new MutableBigInteger();
    MutableBigInteger mdivisor = new MutableBigInteger(bdivisor.mag);
    MutableBigInteger mr = mdividend.divide(mdivisor, mq);
    ...
```

And this is where the error is introduced: The `mdivididend` is a **mutable** `BigInteger`, that was created as a mutable view on the `mag` array of the `BigInteger` that is stored in the `BigDecimal` `x` from the original call. The division modifies the `mag` field, and thus, the state of the (now not-so-immutable) `BigDecimal`.

This is clearly a bug in the implementation of one of the `divide` methods. I already started tracking the change sets of the OpenJDK, but have not yet spotted the definite culprit. (*Edit: See updates below*)

(A side note: Calling `x.toString()` before doing the division does not really *avoid*, but only *hide* the bug: It causes a string cache of the correct state to be created internally. The right value is printed, but the internal state is still wrong - which is concerning, to say the least...)

---

> **Update**: To confirm what `@MikeM` said: Bug has been listed on [openjdk bug list](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066842) and it has been resolved in `JDK8 Build 51`
>
> **Update** : Kudos to Mike and exex zian for digging out the bug reports. According to the discussion there, the bug was introduced with [this changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/ffada2ce20e5#l1.1174).
> <sub>(Admittedly, while skimming through the changes, I also considered this as a hot candidate, but could not believe that this was introduced *four years ago* and remained unnoticed until now...)</sub>

Comment: I can confirm that the bug is fixed in java 8 update 60.